# An error occurred while calling o168.showString. org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue

While writing a parquet file or while using df.show() in AWS glue , it is giving the following error. This is happening when I am reading the parquet file using a schema. I am using the following function to read it

```
def parquet_to_dataframe(location,schema):
    csv_df = (
        spark.read.option("header", True).schema(schema).parquet(location)      
    )
    return csv_df
```

Any help on where I am going wrong or what should be modified would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need specify the schema while reading the parquet file.

below piece of code will show you the data

```
   df = spark.read.parquet(location)
   df.show(10, False)
```

and if you want to convert that as CSV then just do

```
 df.write.csv(path=<location>, header='true')
```

above line will save the data as csv file.

please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: So it throws this error when I am reading without a schema . An error occurred while calling o67.parquet. Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_8);